# If $f$ is holomorphic in the unit ball and $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for $|z|< 1$ then $|f'(0)|\leq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Came across this problem today. Its enunciate is quite simple: I am given $f$ holomorphic in $B(0,1)\subset\mathbb{C}$ (unit ball centered on $0$) with the condition $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for all $|z|< 1$, then $|f'(0)|\leq 1$.

None of the complex analisys' classical theorems seems to apply here and using Taylor Series wasn't helpful. Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems so. I didn't know that it had this name. I'll take a look. thanks!

Comment: Do you know if $f(0) = 0$?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan no, that's not assumed.

Answer (score 2):

If $|f(z)|=1$ for some $z$ then $f$ is constant and $f'(0)=0$.  Otherwise let $$ g(z) = \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{1-\overline{f(0)}f(z)}$$ for $z$ in the unit disc. Then $g$ is holomorphic, $|g(z)| < 1$ for all $z$ and $g(0)=0$.  By Schwarz' lemma $$ \frac{|f'(0)|}{1-|f(0)|^2} = |g'(0)| \leq 1.$$